# Get marked control and when combination of keys is pressed save it into a file

Tags: c#, winforms, file, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm making a program in C# using WinForms. When user presses a combination of keys, e. g. SHIFT+A, my program determines that - I already setup that with a keyboard hook.

What I need is that program knows what is selected or marked such as text, image, app etc. When a user presses SHIFT+A, what is selected program save into a created file in directory which is already done. How do I get the selected control into the created file? How do I get what is selected into a text file and save it or write the marked control into the created file.

I tried to find the answer on the internet, but there are only answers for the TextBox control.

Comment: When you say "a program knows" are you talking about YOUR program having knowledge of OTHER programs running on windows OR with-in YOUR program? I really think you should spend some time to give us a use-case because at the moment it is hard to visualize what you are asking for.

Comment: I want that my program will knew that.

Comment: Will know what? You did not answer my question

Comment: I'am asking that I need to do that when user will press SHIFT + A the program will determind the selected text and save it into the text file which I already created?

Comment: Okay, I understand that but are you asking for this functionality with-in YOUR program OR you want this to work when you minimize your program and press SHIFT+A globally and get selected text?

Comment: I wanted in both way and i done that with keyboard global hook what i'am asking you guys is how i get selected text into a txt file which program crates when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the control that is focused you can use: `this.ActiveControl` or `this.ActiveControl.Name`.

Then you need a method for each control type, that defines how it is saved to a file. Dependent if it's `picturebox` a textbox, ...

Comment: This thing will do what...?

Comment: I think there is no way to get the selected item of a winform. but instead with this method you could check which control/item has the focus.

Comment: So I copy this code to the section where program or hook is checking if 2 keys are pressed and if it's true it return this code?

Comment: when you decide what you want to save to a file you can use `this.ActiveControl` to get the control or `this.ActiveControl.Name` to get the name of that control. (I edited the answer to make it more simple)

Comment: Thanks for that one more question can i used this for when some text is selected...